# how to use imagemagick in a python script?

Tags: python, image, pdf, imagemagick-convert

Trying to use ImageMagick in a Python script. I can convert any pdf file to PNG image using Image Magic code as follows.  This is what I came up with.

```
convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png
```

Is there any way to embed the above code `convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png` in python script to convert pdf to an image?

Comment: Take a look at [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). It can also be done in Python without depending on imagemagick by using [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a subprocess call in Python.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```